# Get the innerText of an element, but exclude hidden children

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I get text from a node so that it returns it with whitespace formatting like "innerText" does, but excludes descendant nodes that are hidden (style display:none)?

Comment: Clone the element, find the hidden descendants, remove them, get the `innerText` of the cloned element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As the OP points out in comments below, even though [MDN clearly states that IE introduced `innerText` to exclude hidden content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent), testing in IE indicates that is not the case.  To summarize:

- Chrome: `innerText` returns text only from *visible* elements.
- IE: `innerText` returns all text, regardless of the element's visibility.
- Firefox: `innerText` is undefined ([as indicated by the W3C](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html), and in my testing).

Add all of this up, and you have a property to avoid like the plague.  Read on for the solution....

If you want cross-browser compatibility, you'll have to roll your own function.  Here's one that works well:

```
function getVisibleText( node ) {
    if( node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ) return node.textContent;
    var style = getComputedStyle( node );
    if( style && style.display === 'none' ) return '';
    var text = '';
    for( var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++ ) 
        text += getVisibleText( node.childNodes[i] );
    return text;
}
```

If you want to get *painfully* clever, you can create a property on the `Node` object so that this feels more "natural".  At first I thought this would be a clever way to polyfill the `innerText` property on Firefox, but that property is not created as a property on the `Node` object prototype, so you would really be playing with fire there.  However, you can create a new property, say `textContentVisible`:

```
Object.defineProperty( Node.prototype, 'textContentVisible', {
    get: function() { 
       return getVisibleText( this );
    }, 
    enumerable: true
});
```

Here's a JsFiddle demonstrating these techniques: http://jsfiddle.net/8S82d/

Comment: Interesting - I'm not seeing the behavior you describe in IE. "innerText" is returning text from span elements that are set to display = none. Also, the function you provide also grabs the text nodes that represent carriage returns - "innerText" seems to exclude those.

Comment: Yes, you can kill carriage returns in this function if you want -- that's one advantage of this approach.  You can modify it to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hm.  I haven't tested in IE...in Chrome, `innerText` does not return hidden elements.  Which is odd, because IE was the browser that introduced it.

Comment: Just tested in IE, and you're right: `innerText` does return hidden elements.  Weird.  Anyway, one more reason to avoid it: it does one thing in Chrome, doesn't exist in Firefox, and another thing in IE.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I need it to kill the carriage returns, and pretty much format it just as if I used "innerText". You've given me a starting point to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting, I came here because I was looking for why the text of `display:none` elements was omitted in Chrome.

So, this was ultimately my solution.
Basically, I clone the node and remove the classes/styling that set `display:none`.

## How to add hidden element's `innerText`

```
function getInnerText(selector) {
    let d = document.createElement('div')
    d.innerHTML = document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML.replaceAll(' class="hidden"', '')
    return d.innerText
}
```